# Corner widgets overlap the tab in QTabWidget

Tags: python, pyqt, pyside, qtabwidget

I have added some widgets into the corner in a QTabWidget using setCornerWidget(), but there are still some problems.

[image]

1. The corner widgets overlap the tab. How can I set some margin to keep them away from tabs?
2. The corner widgets stay at the bottom of tab bar. What can I do to center them vertically in the tab bar?

main.py:

```
import sys
from PySide6.QtWidgets import *
from classes.tab import Tab

app = QApplication(sys.argv)
screen = Tab()
screen.show()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

tab.py (just put this in a folder called classes):

```
from PySide6.QtCore import *
from PySide6.QtWidgets import *
from interfaces.tab_ui import Ui_tabWidgetForm
from interfaces.c_widget_ui import Ui_Form


class CornerWidget(QWidget, Ui_Form):

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.setupUi(self)


class Tab(QWidget, Ui_tabWidgetForm):

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.setupUi(self)

        label1 = QLabel("Widget in tab 1.")
        label2 = QLabel("Widget in tab 2.")
        label3 = QLabel("Widget in tab 3.")
        label4 = QLabel("Widget in tab 4.")
        self.tabWidget.addTab(label1, "Tab 1")
        self.tabWidget.addTab(label2, "Tab 2")
        self.tabWidget.addTab(label3, "Tab 3")
        self.tabWidget.addTab(label4, "Tab 4")

        cornerWidget = CornerWidget()
        self.tabWidget.setCornerWidget(cornerWidget, Qt.TopRightCorner)
```

c_widget_ui.py (just put this in a folder called interfaces):

```
from PySide6.QtCore import *
from PySide6.QtWidgets import *

class Ui_Form(object):

    def setupUi(self, Form):
        if not Form.objectName():
            Form.setObjectName(u"Form")
        Form.resize(237, 30)
        Form.setMinimumSize(QSize(100, 30))
        Form.setMaximumSize(QSize(237, 30))
        self.horizontalLayout = QHBoxLayout(Form)
        self.horizontalLayout.setSpacing(0)
        self.horizontalLayout.setObjectName(u"horizontalLayout")
        self.horizontalLayout.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        self.widget = QWidget(Form)
        self.widget.setObjectName(u"widget")
        self.horizontalLayout_2 = QHBoxLayout(self.widget)
        self.horizontalLayout_2.setObjectName(u"horizontalLayout_2")
        self.horizontalLayout_2.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        self.pushButton = QPushButton(self.widget)
        self.pushButton.setObjectName(u"pushButton")

        self.horizontalLayout_2.addWidget(self.pushButton)

        self.pushButton_2 = QPushButton(self.widget)
        self.pushButton_2.setObjectName(u"pushButton_2")

        self.horizontalLayout_2.addWidget(self.pushButton_2)

        self.pushButton_3 = QPushButton(self.widget)
        self.pushButton_3.setObjectName(u"pushButton_3")

        self.horizontalLayout_2.addWidget(self.pushButton_3)

        self.horizontalLayout.addWidget(self.widget)

        self.retranslateUi(Form)

        QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(Form)

    # setupUi

    def retranslateUi(self, Form):
        Form.setWindowTitle(QCoreApplication.translate("Form", u"Form", None))
        self.pushButton.setText(
            QCoreApplication.translate("Form", u"PushButton", None))
        self.pushButton_2.setText(
            QCoreApplication.translate("Form", u"PushButton", None))
        self.pushButton_3.setText(
            QCoreApplication.translate("Form", u"PushButton", None))

    # retranslateUi
```

tab_ui.py (just put this in a folder called interfaces):

```
from PySide6.QtCore import *
from PySide6.QtWidgets import *


class Ui_tabWidgetForm(object):

    def setupUi(self, tabWidgetForm):
        if not tabWidgetForm.objectName():
            tabWidgetForm.setObjectName(u"tabWidgetForm")
        tabWidgetForm.resize(662, 599)
        tabWidgetForm.setStyleSheet(u"QWidget{\n"
                                    "   background-color: rgb(205, 203, 201);\n"
                                    "   color: rgb(38, 38, 38);\n"
                                    "}")
        self.verticalLayout = QVBoxLayout(tabWidgetForm)
        self.verticalLayout.setSpacing(0)
        self.verticalLayout.setObjectName(u"verticalLayout")
        self.verticalLayout.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        self.layout = QWidget(tabWidgetForm)
        self.layout.setObjectName(u"layout")
        self.verticalLayout_3 = QVBoxLayout(self.layout)
        self.verticalLayout_3.setSpacing(0)
        self.verticalLayout_3.setObjectName(u"verticalLayout_3")
        self.verticalLayout_3.setContentsMargins(0, 4, 0, 0)
        self.tabWidget = QTabWidget(self.layout)
        self.tabWidget.setObjectName(u"tabWidget")
        self.tabWidget.setStyleSheet(
            u"QTabWidget::tab-bar {\n"
            "   left: 8px;\n"
            "}\n"
            "\n"
            "QTabBar::tab {\n"
            "   border-top-left-radius: 5px;\n"
            "   border-top-right-radius: 5px;\n"
            "   width: 35ex;\n"
            "   padding: 8px;\n"
            "}\n"
            "\n"
            "QTabBar::tab:selected {\n"
            "   background: rgb(247, 245, 243);\n"
            "   margin-bottom: -1px;\n"
            "   margin-left: 2px;\n"
            "   margin-right: 2px;\n"
            "   border-bottom: 1px solid rgb(247, 245, 243);\n"
            "}\n"
            "\n"
            "QTabBar::tab:!selected {\n"
            "   background: rgba(247, 245, 243, 80);\n"
            "   border-radius: 8px;\n"
            "   padding: 4px;\n"
            "   border-top: 4px solid rgb(205, 203, 201);\n"
            "   border-bottom: 4px solid rgb(205, 203, 201);\n"
            "   border-left: 2px solid rgb(205, 203, 201);\n"
            "   border-right: 2px solid rgb(205, 203, 201);\n"
            "}\n"
            "\n"
            "QTabWidget::pane {\n"
            "   border: 3px solid rgb(247, 245, 243);\n"
            "}\n"
            "\n"
            "QTabBar::scroller {\n"
            "    width: 40px;\n"
            "}\n"
            "\n"
            "QTabBar QToolButton {\n"
            "   background-color: rgb(243, 242, 241);\n"
            "   border: 1px solid rgb(138, 136, 134);\n"
            "}\n"
            "\n"
            "QTabBar QToolButton:hover{\n"
            "   background-color: rgb(225, 22"
            "3, 221);\n"
            "}\n"
            "\n"
            "QTabBar QToolButton:pressed{\n"
            "   background-color: rgb(210, 208, 206);\n"
            "}\n"
            "")
        self.tabWidget.setTabShape(QTabWidget.Rounded)
        self.tabWidget.setElideMode(Qt.ElideRight)
        self.tabWidget.setUsesScrollButtons(True)
        self.tabWidget.setTabsClosable(True)
        self.tabWidget.setMovable(True)

        self.verticalLayout_3.addWidget(self.tabWidget)

        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.layout)

        self.retranslateUi(tabWidgetForm)

        self.tabWidget.setCurrentIndex(-1)

        QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(tabWidgetForm)

    # setupUi

    def retranslateUi(self, tabWidgetForm):
        tabWidgetForm.setWindowTitle(
            QCoreApplication.translate("tabWidgetForm", u"Form", None))

    # retranslateUi
```

Comment: Provide a [mre] with the code of the ui classes (or, better, the contents of the ui files).